# AWS CloudFront Not Forwarding Server-Sent Events: "This request could not be satisfied"

Tags: amazon-web-services, backend, amazon-cloudfront, server-sent-events

I'm currently working with AWS CloudFront as a CDN for my web application, which relies on Server-Sent Events (SSE) for real-time functionality. However, I've run into an issue where CloudFront seems not to be forwarding SSE properly, and a few minutes into the connection, it drops with the error message "This request could not be satisfied."

The API hits the API Gateway however the events do not reach to me. Could you help me identify the issue here as I couldn't seem to find any relatable resource that could help me identify this issue.